What is the correct way to calculate the odds of a flush post flop?
Scenario: You have two hearts, and the board has two hearts.
How I see the odds of a flush calculated everywhere:

you have 9 outs left, and 47 unseen cards.
Odds of hitting your flush: (9/47) + (9/46) - ((9/47)*(9/46)) = 34.97%
This calculation makes sense, we're taking the odds of hitting on the turn OR river minus hitting on BOTH.
I interpret this result as: When you are in this exact scenario, 34.97% of the time you will make a flush.

But I am confused because if we are in a 6 man game, why are we not taking the other players hands into account!?!? I have read that the unseen cards of the other players is irrelevant to the calculation, but here is how I thought you would calculate the odds.
Here is my calculation:

6 player game, 12 cards have been dealt
Your hand has 2 hearts and the board has 2 hearts.
9 outs, and 47 cards left
HOWEVER, there are 10 other cards, AND ON AVERAGE, (9/47)*10 of those cards will be hearts. 1.915 of those cards will be hearts
NOW you have 7.085 outs ON AVERAGE, and 37 cards left
Odds of hitting your flush: (7.085/37) + (7.085/36) - ((7.085/37)(7.085/36)) = 35.06%
If you have a 10 person game of poker these odds become 35.18%

I know the difference in these odds is somewhat insignificant, but why is it that we don't account for the other players in the game? I am mix of confused/curious.
Any insight is appreciated, thank you!

CORRECTED ANSWER: My calculation should be: (7.085/37) + (7.043/36) - ((7.085/37)(7.043/36)) = 34.97% (same as others) instead of 7.085/36 it should be (9-(9/46)*10)/36 which is 7.043/36
